# How do I get SQLite on my android

Tags: android

I'm in my cmd prompt and im adb shell. When I try to run sqlite3 it shows this error. Please help..

```
cd /system/xbin/sqlite
sh: cd: /system/xbin/sqlite - No such file or directory
1|shell@android:/system/xbin # cd /system/xbin/sqlite3
cd /system/xbin/sqlite3
sh: cd: /system/xbin/sqlite3 - No such file or directory
1|shell@android:/system/xbin #
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not trying to "run sqlite3". You are trying to change to a directory -- that is what the `cd` command means in Linux.

On an emulator, to run the `sqlite3` command from the `adb shell`, simply type `sqlite3`, then press `<Enter>`:

```
# sqlite3
SQLite version 3.7.4
Enter ".help" for instructions
Enter SQL statements terminated with a ";"
sqlite>
```

Note that the `sqlite3` command does not exist on production devices AFAIK.

Comment: afaik? 

`C:\Program Files\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools>adb shell
shell@android:/ $ su
su
shell@android:/ # sqlite3
sqlite3
sh: sqlite3: not found
127|shell@android:/ #`

Comment: @YusefBee: Are you attempting to use `sqlite3` on a phone or other Android device? In that case, as far as I know (AFAIK), it will not work.

Comment: I am trying to use it on my Galaxy Nexus from Windows command prompt.

Comment: I want to get the contacts off my actual phone, sorry that's what I was trying to do..

Comment: @YusefBee: That will not be possible unless you root your phone. Then you can copy the database off your rooted phone onto your local machine for examination.

Comment: My phone is rooted @CommonsWare. How can I do this?

Comment: @YusefBee: StackOverflow is for programming questions. Learning how to copy a file off a rooted device is not a programming question. I suspect that there are many places that cover this on the Internet findable by a search engine. Otherwise, try http://android.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 0):

In the command prompt Go to this path or set as classpath F:\PROJECTS\ANDROID\android-sdk_r10-windows\android-sdk-windows\tools

Then type

adb shell

u will see

#

type

## sqlite3 /data/data/com.yourpackage/databases/yourdbname

you will enter sqlite database

Comment: It still says Sqlite not found.

`shell@android:/ # sqlite3  /data/data/com.android.providers.contacts/databases/c
ontacts2.db
d.providers.contacts/databases/contacts2.db                                   <
sh: sqlite3: not found
127|shell@android:/ #`

Comment: the same command is works for me ...specify ur package name and ur database name properly then u got

Comment: but there is no sqlite (nor sqlite3) on Galaxy Nexus, why ?

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to run the sqlite database for an app you're working on? Here is the commands I use when running the emulator.

adb shell

cd data/data/app_name/databases

sqlite3 database name

Comment: `shell@android:/ # sqlite3  /data/data/com.android.providers.contacts/databases/c
ontacts2.db
d.providers.contacts/databases/contacts2.db                                   <
sh: sqlite3: not found
127|shell@android:/ #`